# Is there way to create a virtual machine image from current machine?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware

I have a PC that has windows 7 installed and I'd like to upgrade it to windows 10. Since there is various old software installed in the current system, to prevent them from not running on the new system, I hope to save the current state to an image.

Is there way to create a virtual machine image from current machine?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. VMware Converter P to V.   You may need to search for VMware Vcenter Converter.

Comment: @John Thanks. I will investigate it.

Comment: Have you tried to google this before asking?